# Aurelia event aggregator VS getter method for two-way data binding

Tags: typescript, aurelia

I'm new to Aurelia and learning about how to use two-way data binding correctly.

The application I'm working on right now will be composed of multiple sub-apps, each with their own sidebar links (menu) and stuff. The applications can be changed easily at any time using a switcher or the dashboard.

I've noticed that I can't bind an if to a method on the model, as the method doesn't get called periodically:

```js
export class App {
    public getMenu() {
        return this.someService.currentApp !== null
            ? this.someService.currentApp.menu
            : [];
    }
}
```

```
<div if.bind="getMenu().length > 0"></div>
```

The code there is pretty long, so putting it in the template doesn't make sense.

However, if I switch this code to a TS getter instead, everything works great:

```js
export class App {
    get menu() {
        return this.someService.currentApp !== null
            ? this.someService.currentApp.menu
            : [];
    }
}
```

```
<div if.bind="menu.length > 0"></div>
```

However, before I noticed this works, I also tried using the Event Aggregator. I fire an event when the app is changed and subscribe to it on the `App` ViewModel:

```js
export class App {
    public menu: AppMenuLink[];

    public constructor(ea: EventAggregator) {
        ea.subscribe('app:changed', (response) => {
            this.menu = response.app !== null ? response.app.menu : [];
        });
    }
}
```

```
<div if.bind="menu.length > 0"></div>
```

This method works too (obviously), but I feel like it could make my code too bloated with event subscribers if I abuse it too much in the long run.

So, my question is: Which method is better (and why), or am I missing something completely and doing this all wrong? I'd like to get this clarified before my codebase gets big.

Also (this probably should be another question), while I'm at using the event aggregator, is there a way to let the template know *what* data to display (when it changes on the event callback), rather than have it check if it changed? I'm thinking this could stop useless checks done by Aurelia to see if the property has changed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not create a getter and use the `computedFrom` decorator to avoid dirty checking?

```
@computedFrom('someService.currentApp.menu.length')
get menuLength() {
  return this.someService.currentApp !== null
    ? this.someService.currentApp.menu.length
    : 0;
}
```

You'd have to test this to see if it works. If it does, awesome! If not, let me know and I'll give some other options.

Comment: Are you certain that this wont create any dirty checking ? From what i have learnt about aurelia, once binding system hits a getter (which in this case is the length of the array), it will create a dirty checker.

But I should be wrong, as this looks like a normal AST for the binding so it will just do it differently.

Either case, it would be great if you could clarify this :)

Comment: That's what the `computedFrom` decorator is for. It allows you to tell Aurelia "only call this getter if this property or properties have changed.

Comment: I like my Aurelia binding code to emulate me: as lazy as possible!

Comment: Not sure when nested property was supported, but the last time i read something about `computedFrom`, it wasn't. This is great.

Comment: Let me know if it isn't. I believe it is, since all that happens is the binding engine parses the string just like it would a binding expression.

Comment: It works, awesome! I had to change the @computedFrom decorator to 'someService.currentApp.menu.length', the _this_ doesn't seem to belong there.

Comment: Makes sense. I should have caught that.